# Why am I obtaining this "Unsupported data type : TEXT as input parameter" trying to perform a WSO2 DSS insert query?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am finding some dificulties trying to implement this simple **WSO2 DSS** service that perform an **insert** query on a **MySql** database.

I have implemented this service:

```
<data name="user-dss" transports="http https local">
    <config id="user_db">
        <property name="driverClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/digital_services_DB</property>
        <property name="username">MY_USERNAME</property>
        <property name="password">MY_PSWD</property>
    </config>
    <query id="insert_user" returnGeneratedKeys="true" useConfig="user_db">
        <sql>
            insert into User(
                application_UID,
                country_id,
                localization_id,
                local_user_id,
                isActive,
                isFullProfile
                )
            values(
                :application_UID,
                :country_id,
                :localization_id,
                :local_user_id,
                :is_active,
                :is_full_profile
            )
        </sql>
        <result element="GeneratedKeys" rowName="Entry" useColumnNumbers="true">
            <element column="1" name="ID" xsdType="integer"/>
        </result>
        <param name="application_UID" sqlType="TEXT"/>
        <param name="country_id" sqlType="BIGINT"/>
        <param name="localization_id" sqlType="BIGINT"/>
        <param name="local_user_id" sqlType="BIGINT"/>
        <param name="is_active" sqlType="BIT"/>
        <param name="is_full_profile" sqlType="BIT"/>
    </query>

    <operation name="AddUser">
        <call-query href="insert_user">
            <with-param name="application_UID" query-param="application_uid"/>
            <with-param name="country_id" query-param="country_id"/>
            <with-param name="localization_id" query-param="localization_id"/>
            <with-param name="local_user_id" query-param="local_user_id"/>
            <with-param name="is_active" query-param="is_active"/>
            <with-param name="is_full_profile" query-param="is_full_profile"/>
        </call-query>
    </operation>
</data>
```

Into my **User** table the **application_UID** field have **TEXT** as SQL type.

The problem is that when I try to perform this query calling the service using the DSS Try It tool, performing the following call into the Try It tool:

```
<body>
   <p:AddUser xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:application_UID>ABC123</p:application_UID>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:country_id>2</p:country_id>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:localization_id>2</p:localization_id>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:local_user_id>2000</p:local_user_id>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:is_active>1</p:is_active>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:is_full_profile>1</p:is_full_profile>
   </p:AddUser>
</body>
```

I obtain the following error into the WSO2 log and the query is not performed:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-18 12:41:48,376] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver} -  Error in in-out message receiver {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver}
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': DS Fault Message: [user-dss]  Found Unsupported data type : TEXT as input parameter.
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR

DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: user-dss
Location: /opt/wso2/wso2ei/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1516275560106userreg-cap_1.0.0.car/user-dss_1.0.0/user-dss-1.0.0.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: AddUser
Current Params: {local_user_id=2000, is_active=1, is_full_profile=1, application_UID=ABC123, country_id=2, localization_id=2}
Nested Exception:-
DS Fault Message: [user-dss]  Found Unsupported data type : TEXT as input parameter.
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR



        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.DataServiceRequest.dispatch(DataServiceRequest.java:357)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DataServiceProcessor.dispatch(DataServiceProcessor.java:41)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(DBInOutMessageReceiver.java:57)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:42)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:404)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': DS Fault Message: [user-dss]  Found Unsupported data type : TEXT as input parameter.
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR

DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: user-dss
Location: /opt/wso2/wso2ei/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1516275560106userreg-cap_1.0.0.car/user-dss_1.0.0/user-dss-1.0.0.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: AddUser
Current Params: {local_user_id=2000, is_active=1, is_full_profile=1, application_UID=ABC123, country_id=2, localization_id=2}
Nested Exception:-
DS Fault Message: [user-dss]  Found Unsupported data type : TEXT as input parameter.
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR


        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:73)
        ... 12 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-18 12:41:48,384] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker} -  Error processing POST request for : /services/user-dss.SOAP12Endpoint/AddUser {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': DS Fault Message: [user-dss]  Found Unsupported data type : TEXT as input parameter.
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR

DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: user-dss
Location: /opt/wso2/wso2ei/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1516275560106userreg-cap_1.0.0.car/user-dss_1.0.0/user-dss-1.0.0.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: AddUser
Current Params: {local_user_id=2000, is_active=1, is_full_profile=1, application_UID=ABC123, country_id=2, localization_id=2}
Nested Exception:-
DS Fault Message: [user-dss]  Found Unsupported data type : TEXT as input parameter.
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR



        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBUtils.createAxisFault(DBUtils.java:740)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(DBInOutMessageReceiver.java:67)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:42)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:404)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': DS Fault Message: [user-dss]  Found Unsupported data type : TEXT as input parameter.
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR

DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: user-dss
Location: /opt/wso2/wso2ei/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1516275560106userreg-cap_1.0.0.car/user-dss_1.0.0/user-dss-1.0.0.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: AddUser
Current Params: {local_user_id=2000, is_active=1, is_full_profile=1, application_UID=ABC123, country_id=2, localization_id=2}
Nested Exception:-
DS Fault Message: [user-dss]  Found Unsupported data type : TEXT as input parameter.
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR


        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:73)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.DataServiceRequest.dispatch(DataServiceRequest.java:357)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DataServiceProcessor.dispatch(DataServiceProcessor.java:41)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(DBInOutMessageReceiver.java:57)
        ... 9 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-18 12:41:48,376] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver} -  Error in in-out message receiver {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver}
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': DS Fault Message: [user-dss]  Found Unsupported data type : TEXT as input parameter.
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR

DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: user-dss
Location: /opt/wso2/wso2ei/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1516275560106userreg-cap_1.0.0.car/user-dss_1.0.0/user-dss-1.0.0.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: AddUser
Current Params: {local_user_id=2000, is_active=1, is_full_profile=1, application_UID=ABC123, country_id=2, localization_id=2}
Nested Exception:-
DS Fault Message: [user-dss]  Found Unsupported data type : TEXT as input parameter.
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR



        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.DataServiceRequest.dispatch(DataServiceRequest.java:357)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DataServiceProcessor.dispatch(DataServiceProcessor.java:41)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(DBInOutMessageReceiver.java:57)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:42)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:404)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': DS Fault Message: [user-dss]  Found Unsupported data type : TEXT as input parameter.
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR

DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: user-dss
Location: /opt/wso2/wso2ei/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1516275560106userreg-cap_1.0.0.car/user-dss_1.0.0/user-dss-1.0.0.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: AddUser
Current Params: {local_user_id=2000, is_active=1, is_full_profile=1, application_UID=ABC123, country_id=2, localization_id=2}
Nested Exception:-
DS Fault Message: [user-dss]  Found Unsupported data type : TEXT as input parameter.
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR


        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:73)
        ... 12 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-18 12:41:48,384] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker} -  Error processing POST request for : /services/user-dss.SOAP12Endpoint/AddUser {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': DS Fault Message: [user-dss]  Found Unsupported data type : TEXT as input parameter.
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR

DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: user-dss
Location: /opt/wso2/wso2ei/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1516275560106userreg-cap
```

So the problem seems to be related to this error message:

```
DS Fault Message: [user-dss]  Found Unsupported data type : TEXT as input parameter.
```

It seems that **TEXT** is not a valid type. But how is it possible? **TEXT** is a valid SQL type.

What can I do to solve this problem and insert a **TEXT** value into the **application_UID** table column?

Answer (score 0):

In Dataservice code when validating input parameters we check whether the sqlType falls in to certain datatypes and if not the given exception is thrown. You can find the relevant code base from [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-data/blob/master/components/data-services/org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/dataservices/core/description/query/SQLQuery.java#L1502). Most of data types are evaluated here, but there can be some missing data types too. However, in order to avoid this issue, you can use the sqlType as string, as at the end it registers the output param as java.sql.Types.VARCHAR and there is no text specific type in [SQL Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html) as well